# What is the purpose of using private set for Commands in a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I've recently begun studying the use of Commands within the MVVM design pattern and notice that in most of the examples I find online, in tutorials, books, etc., the `ICommand` object in the VM uses the auto-property setter of `private set`. These same examples also show that the `ICommand` object is being instantiated and assigned in the VM constructor, which is permissible without this auto-property setter. Therefore, my question is, what is the purpose of using `private set` with ICommand objects (assuming the ICommand object is not being reassigned after the VM is constructed)?

The reason I raise this is because Visual Studio suggests that I remove `private set` from these `ICommand` objects, and I'm wondering whether there is any reason not to follow that recommendation.

Edit:
This is not a duplicate as proposed. The proposed duplicate does clearly explain the use of private set, but it does not comment on whether there is an idiosyncrasy related to ICommand, which is the purpose of my question. Thanks to the answer I received, I learned that there is not, and that it is simply a difference in C# versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property with getter only vs. with getter and private setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035632/property-with-getter-only-vs-with-getter-and-private-setter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With versions of C# older than C# 6 the private setter was required for auto properties. From C# 6 private setter for auto properties is not obligatory and can be omitted if the property is assigned in constructor or property initializer. [Here](http://codebetter.com/derikwhittaker/2014/11/18/c-6-features-private-auto-properties/) is a nice explanation.